# How to create sub list with fixed length from given number of inputs or list in Python?

Tags: python, list, subset

I want to create sub-lists with fixed list length, from given number of inputs in Python.

For example, my inputs are: `['a','b','c',......'z']`... Then I want to put those values in several lists. Each list length should be 6. So I want something like this:

```
first list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

`second list = ['g','h','i','j','k','l']`

```
last list = [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','z' ]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will split your list into 2 lists of equal length (6):

```
>>> my_list = [1, 'ab', '', 'No', '', 'NULL', 2, 'bc', '','Yes' ,'' ,'Null']
>>> x = my_list[:len(my_list)//2]
>>> y = my_list[len(my_list)//2:]
>>> x
[1, 'ab', '', 'No', '', 'NULL']
>>> y
[2, 'bc', '', 'Yes', '', 'Null']
```

If you want to split a list to *many* smaller lists use:

```
chunks = [my_list[x:x+size] for x in range(0, len(my_list), size)]
```

Where `size` is the size of the smaller lists you want, example:

```
>>> size = 2
>>> chunks = [my_list[x:x+size] for x in range(0, len(my_list), size)]
[[1, 'ab'], ['', 'No'], ['', 'NULL'], [2, 'bc'], ['', 'Yes'], ['', 'Null']]
>>> for item in chunks:
        print (item)
[1, 'ab']
['', 'No']
['', 'NULL']
[2, 'bc']
['', 'Yes']
['', 'Null']
```

Comment: this solution is for 2 rows... but for more than that means?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed I don't understand, what is the problem?

Comment: i am having number of values ... for ex, 'a','b','c',......'z'... then i want to put those values in several lists. each list length should be 6... so i want like this, first list - ['a','b','c','d','e','f'], second list, ['g','h','i','j','k','l']  .... last list - [' ',' ',' ',' ',' ','z' ]

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed see my edit it's the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

The smallest solution:

```
    x = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]
    size = 3 (user input)
    for counter in range(0,len(x),size):
        print(x[counter:counter+size])
```

Answer (score 1):

This returns a 2d list "b" that contains as many entries per list as chunksize is big.

```
a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
b = []
chunksize = 6
def get_list(a, chunk):
    return a[chunk*chunksize:chunk*chunksize+chunksize]
for i in range(int(len(a) / chunksize)):
    b.append(get_list(a,i))
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'], ['m', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r'], ['s', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is a string, and you need to split it first by comma, and then divide it further:

```
input_string = "1, 'ab', '', 'No', '', 'NULL', 2, 'bc', '','Yes' ,'' ,'Null'"
bits = input_string.split(',')
x,y = bits[:6],bits[6:] # divide by 6
x,y = bits[:len(bits)//2],bits[len(bits)//2:] # divide in half
```